# Concatenate and replace strings after groupBy in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having below dataframe `df`, I need to groupby based on `constraint` column and concatenate `status` column values.

```
   +--------------------+-----_-+                                          
   |          constraint|status |
   +--------------------+-------+
   |Test1               |Success|
   |Test1               |Success|
   |Test2               |Failure|
   |Test2               |Success|
   |Test3               |Success|
   |Test3               |Success|
   |Test4               |Failure|
   |Test4               |Success|
   +--------------------+-------+
```

Expected Output:

- Success, Success -> Success
- Success, Failure -> Failure

  ```
  +--------------------+-------+
  |          constraint|status |
  +--------------------+-------+
  |Test1               |Success|
  |Test2               |Failure|
  |Test3               |Success|
  |Test4               |Failure|
  +--------------------+-------+
  ```

I tried below to groupBy `constraint` column. Then remove duplicate words and replace 'Success Failure' to Failure

Please let me know for optimised way of getting expected output.

Code:

```
val result_group = df.groupBy(col1 = "constraint").agg(concat_ws(" ", 
collect_list("constraint_status")) as "combined_status")
val distinct :String => String = _.split(" ").toSet.mkString(",")
val validation_status = udf (distinct)
result_group.select('constraint,validation_status('combined_status).as("distinct")).show
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work efficiently:

```scala
val df = spark
.read
.option("header","true")
.option("delimiter","|")
.csv("tmp.csv")
.withColumn("status_code", when($"status"==="Success", 0)
.otherwise(1))
.groupBy("constraint")
.agg(max("status_code").as("status_code"))
.withColumn("status", when($"status_code"===0, "Success")
.otherwise("Failure"))
```

Output:

```scala
df.show()
```

```sh
+----------+-----------+-------+
|constraint|status_code| status|
+----------+-----------+-------+
|     Test2|          1|Failure|
|     Test1|          0|Success|
|     Test3|          1|Failure|
+----------+-----------+-------+
```

Format of the input csv I used:

```sh
constraint|status
Test1|Success
Test1|Success
Test1|Success
Test1|Success
Test2|Success
Test2|Success
Test2|Failure
Test2|Success
Test3|Success
Test3|Failure
```

Comment: Nice, although I would naturally use 1 for "Success" (and min for aggregate)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, without conversions

```
val result_group = df.groupBy(col1 = "constraint").
                   agg(collect_set($"constraint_status")) as "combined_status")).
                   withColumn("resulting_status",when(array_contains($"combined_status",lit("Failure")),"Failure").otherwise("Success"))
```

`collect_set` will aggregate to array (sic!) of distinct values, so it will be either ["Success"], or ["Failure"], or ["Success","Failure"], 
`array_contains` will then check if "Failure" is present.

Or you can do `array_sort` and take the first value (relying on "Failure" coming before "Success"). Bit it seems less clear